# How to compare response with global variable in postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I have a global variable defined in postman and I am making a post request. I would like to know whether the response will contain the value that I had set in the global variable.

```
pm.test("Body matches string", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include({{sample_message}});
});
```

**sample_message** is the global variable

How can I compare?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution after lot of research in web

```
pm.test("Body matches string", function () {
  pm.expect(jsonData.data.message_content).to.eql(pm.environment.get("sample_message"));
});
```

This  `pm.environment.get("sample_message")` will fetch the value of the global variable

*Source : [Writing tests in Postman](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/10/25/writing-tests-in-postman/)*

Answer (score 2):

Postman cannot solve {{}} variables in test tab.

Replace {{sample_message}} by `postman.getGlobalVariable("sample_message")`